# What does my chop say? And what’s its correct orientation?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This image is a chop stamp that was made for me; I was told it is not a representation of my name but of me somehow. I would love to have an accurate translation. (And to know the correct orientation as well.)
[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm completely off, but this looks like 「㝽㘐（哏？）藝師」. I can't make any sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try. It'll take a while. First of all, the orientation is correct. The big word at the bottom left is 師, which means teacher.

And I agree with @dRooze the top left character is 蓺, which means skill or the skill of planting trees.

The right middle character is indeed 㘐, which means loud and is a variant of the commonly used word 炮, gun/cannon.

So the five words are 㝽㘐哏蓺師, or 水炮哏藝師. Are you a firefighter? This says you are the master of water cannon. Did you get this from Hongkong or Canton or where Cantonese is spoken?